# React: The onClick nested within a card is not called

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react hooks, and I have erased out other functions not associated with the function I am intending to call. The App functions are rendered

```
function App() {
  const memoizedCallback = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("Click happened");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactMapGl
        {...viewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={accesstoken}
        onViewportChange={viewport => {
          setviewport(viewport);
        }}
      >
        {details.map(details => (
          <Marker
            key={details.name}
            latitude={details.lat}
            longitude={details.long}
          >
            <button
              class="marker-btn"
              onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                useselectedpark(details);
              }}
            >
              <img src={icon} alt="icon" className="navbar-brand" />
            </button>
          </Marker>
        ))}

        {selectedpark ? (
          <Popup
            latitude={selectedpark.lat}
            longitude={selectedpark.long}
            onClose={() => {
              useselectedpark(null);
            }}
          >
            <div>
              <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{selectedpark.name}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>{selectedpark.postalcode}</Card.Text>
                  <div>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={memoizedCallback}>
                      Visit Gallery
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </div>
          </Popup>
        ) : null}
        {console.log("in render", details)}
      </ReactMapGl>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the function I am intending to call is `memoizedCallback`. The function is called in an `onClick` of a button within a card.

The sequence of events is as such. A popup appears, and the user has an option to click on a button within the card that appears.

**Problem:** Currently, when the button is clicked right now, the function `memoizedCallback` is not called.

Why is that so, what did I miss here?

Comment: did you  read onClick prop in Button component?

Comment: what's the error message

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu Theres no error message the function just doesnt run